# Creating files (.css, .js) with VSCode ends up as chinese letters inside the browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to write a simple web page to test something, but when I create the files with VsCode and modify them the browser does not seem to interpret them correctly in fact it shows Chinese letters as their contents any ideas ?

[image: Css content on browser]

Comment: You might probably wanna check the encoding tag, also the browser language?

Comment: @Muhammad.fatiu if you're referring to the HTML I haven't declared any encoding tag in it and even so what does it have to do with the CSS and JS files and for the browser I tried creating the files with cmd and it worked just fine!

Comment: Go to File > Preferences > Settings > Text Editor > Files > Encoding and make sure it is set to UTF-8.

Comment: @WaisKamal yep it's set to utf8 alright

Comment: Then try reinstalling the application.

Comment: how do you modify the files, you show a screen shot of VSC not the browser, does it work if you use Notepad++ or Vim